# CSS Box expanding bug / feature

Tags: html, css

Found an interesting browser behaviour. Given the following code:

```
div {
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    color: #FFF;
}

.a {
    float: left;
    /* fix either set width or remove float */
    background: goldenrod;
}

.b {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #392;
}

.b div {
    width: 20000em;
    background: #942;
}
```

and

```
<DIV class="a">
    <DIV class="b">
        <DIV>Content</DIV>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

I would expect the `overflow: hidden` to hide/crop the div to the viewport, but the parent float is honoured instead and the page is WIIIIIIIDE.

Anyone know if this a feature or a browser bug?

I know that you *should* add a width to a float ... but this felt weird to me. To stop the behaviour, either remove the `float` on `.a` or add `max-width: 100%` or similar.

[Note: found in html spaghetti mixing ektron, jcarousel with bootstrap, this is simplest test case to reproduce issue.]

Demo at http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/wteya

Comment: There is no overflow because the .a and .b boxex have no width; which tells the browser "have at, I'll go as wide as you want".

Comment: when you float a div it will usually take up the width of it's content unless you specify a specific width for the floated div, so it is expected behaviour

Comment: [Have a look at this for an example of what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/cZLNX/1/)

Comment: set the width of `.a` to `100%` (there will be a padding issue or two).  `100%` means it will get the width of .a's parent (body in your pen)

Comment: Thanks, I have got the logic in my head now and it makes sense. The original code was in a CMS nested tens of divs and other elements deep - finding the bug was a challenge!